# What is the Difference Between fetch and branch in the Git config file

Tags: git-svn

The `config` file of a Git repository has under `[git-svn remotes]` both `fetch` and `branch` paths. The config file can even have multiple `fetch` lines and multiple `branch` lines. What is the reason to have (and what is the difference between) both `fetch` and `branch`? When I do a `git svn fetch --all`, I get updates for the trunk in `fetch` and from all the other `branch` lines as well. So it seems there is no difference. Is there any drawback if I just list all my branches using multiple `branch` and not have **any** `fetch` line?

```
[svn-remote "messy-repo"]
    url = http://server.org/svn
    fetch = trunk/project-a:refs/remotes/project-a/trunk
    fetch = branches/demos/june-project-a-demo:refs/remotes/project-a/demos/june-demo
    branches = branches/server/*:refs/remotes/project-a/branches/*
    branches = branches/demos/2011/*:refs/remotes/project-a/2011-demos/*
```

Comment: Git itself completely ignores these; what git-svn does with them is up to git-svn. I will snip the git tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [illustrated here](https://gist.github.com/trodrigues/1023167/e6689cef40bb3ebe3d06923833483c8809bca981), the first git svn clone does generate a cnfig with `fetch` in it.

> If at any point after this you want to checkout additional branches, you first need to add it on your configuration file:
>
> ```yaml
> [svn-remote "svn"]
>   url = https://example.com/
>   fetch = PROJECT/branches/somefeature:refs/remotes/trunk
>        branches = PROJECT/branches/{anotherfeature}:refs/remotes/*
> ```
>
> The branches config always needs a glob.

From [`git svn clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#Documentation/git-svn.txt-emcloneem)

> After a repository is cloned, the `fetch` command will be able to update revisions without affecting the working tree

The difference:

> It is similar the core Git `[remote]` sections **except `fetch` keys do not accept glob arguments; but they are instead handled by the `branches` and `tags` keys.**